# How to reach a specific XML node by its number (order)?

Tags: xml, vbscript, xml-parsing

I have an XML file that has many nodes with the same name. I need to reach to a specific node, *not by its name nor by its attribute*, but by its **order** of appearance in the XML file. For example:

```
<category field="X"/>
<class LN="RF"/>
<category field="Y"/>
<p name="state"/>
<category field="Z"/>
<category field="A"/>
```

So I need to reach the node `<category field="Z"/>` for example not because its attribute is `="Z"` but because its ***order*** is the third in the group of `category` nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the node occurrence with `[]` or `position()` function of an XPath:

```vb
Public Sub XMLData()
  Dim XmlFile
  Dim doc, item
  Dim fso, stdout

  Set fso = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set stdout = fso.GetStandardStream (1)

  XmlFile = "C:\Path\To\xmlfile.xml"
  doc.Load XmlFile

  For Each item In doc.SelectNodes("//category[3]")  'OR //category[position()=3]'
    stdout.WriteLine item.Attributes.ItemOf("field").InnerText
  Next

  Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the `<category>` nodes with an [XPath expression](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon6.5.3/expressions.html), then use the [`item`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757028%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method for selecting the n-th element from the resulting collection:

```vb
xmldata = "<root>" & _
  "<category field=""X""/>" & _
  "<class LN=""RF""/>" & _
  "<category field=""Y""/>" & _
  "<p name=""state""/>" & _
  "<category field=""Z""/>" & _
  "<category field=""A""/>" & _
  "</root>"

Set xml = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
xml.async = False
xml.loadXml xmldata

If xml.parseError <> 0 Then
  WScript.Echo xml.parseError.Reason
  WScript.Quit xml.parseError
End If

Set categories = xml.selectNodes("//category")
Set thirdCategory = nodes.item(2)

WScript.Echo node.getAttribute("field")
```

Note that the index is zero-based, so you need to use index 2 for the third element.